# Customizing the NavigationBar using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

When I try adding custom attributes to my navigationBar, I get the error: "could not find an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments"...This only started occurring with the most recent Xcode update. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 30), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: (102/255.0), green: (45/255.0), blue: (145/255.0), alpha: 1.0)]
```

Comment: This doesn't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 30)` returns an optional now. (As you correctly state, this only just started, in Xcode 6.1.) You need to unwrap it (put an exclamation mark after it) in order to use it in the attributes dictionary.

Comment: And you might like to file a bug report with Apple asking for a better error message from the Swift compiler in this situation.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much, I appreciate the help. I'll be sure to file that bug report